# ¿no puedo usar la directiva using data?

Tags: c#, data, dataset

estoy aprendiendo C#, no sé mucho sobre IDE, así que puede ser una bobada.

Necesitaba crear una biblioteca de clases, el "profesor" usa el VS 2015, yo uso el 2017, el eligió la unica biblioteca de clases que habia, a mi me salian varias (standard, framework, portable, windows universal) yo elegí la "standard" supuse que sería la común.

Necesito agregar una directiva "Using System.Data;" 
Y después de esa, agregar "Using System.Data.SqlClient;"
Sin embargo no sé porque me marca error, y me dice que ***"el uso de la directiva no es necesario"***

no sé cual puede ser el error, estoy siguiendo un curso, y el que lo dicta lo tiene igual que yo, todo, pero a él no le maca errores. 
Dejo pantallazos.

Necesito poder usar el ***"DataSet"***
Estaré atento, gracias.

[image: Esta es la captura]

[image: captura de lo que dice el error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero que deberias conocer es que al seleccionar `.NET Standard` no es lo mismo que hacer uso del `.net framework full` ya que hay limitantes en cuanto a las librerias que puedes o no utilizar, esto se debe a que estas creando una biblioteca portable que podras usar en diferentes plataformas

[.NET Standard](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/net-standard)

aqui esta mencionado el problema

[Why is there no System.Data in netstandard20?](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/30)

se menciona

> .NET Core already does and will continue to support System.Data. We currently have a dev prototyping adding virtually all of the generic ADO.NET namespaces, i.e. System.Data and System.Data.Common, including DataSet and DataTable

como veras debes usar .net full o quizas ver de aplicar

> The alternative to adding System.Data to the standard would be to provide it as a set of NuGet packages that target .NET Standard.

o sea agregarlas desde nuget

[System.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/)

o sino quieres complicarte crear un proyecto de libreria que use la version completa del framework de .net

Answer (score 0):

**Lo resolví** creando una nueva biblioteca de clases, yo al elegir, opté por crear una **Standard**, y tiene limitaciones, simplemente la eliminé y creé otra biblioteca pero esta vez elegí la **Framework** y listo, solucionado.